# How to start the camel route only after completion of previous route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have multiple routes in my RouteBuilder like below

```
from(
            "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/input/CamelTestIn.csv?fileSystemType=HDFS")
            .to("file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelout/?fileName=CamelTestIn.csv&fileExist=Append");

    from("file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/camelout/?fileName=CamelTestIn.csv&noop=true")

            .unmarshal(csv)
            .convertBodyTo(List.class)
            .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                    List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) msg
                            .getIn().getBody();
                    for (List<String> line : data) {

                        // System.out.println("line "+line);
                        if ("1502873".equals(line.get(3))) {
                            line.set(18, "Y");
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .marshal(csv)
            .to("file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/mytemp/?fileName=outRes.csv");


            from(
            "file:/home/cloudera/Desktop/mytemp/?fileName=outRes.csv&noop=true")
            .to("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/output/?fileSystemType=HDFS")

            .end();
}
```

I am just adding it to context and starting the context.But when I do like this it is not giving correct output(i.e my input file size is 4.1 MB but it is producing only 664 kb output file).I thought that it might be because of continuous routes.So for testing purpose first I commented the last two routes and started the context and then commented the first and last and restarted the context with only one route again and finally commented the first two and again restarted the context with only last route .Now It is working fine .But why it is giving wrong results when I run all the routes at a time.

is there any solution to avoid this issue?

Please suggest me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your file producer write the files into a repository and your file consumer consumes   file from the same repository without knowing that file is still being written.

Pl refer the readLock options from camel file component. If you set the appropriate read lock as per your need, camel file component will not consume the file is being written, it will wait till the file lock is released.

or other wise, you can manually invoke any consumer using consumer template. You can invoke a spring bean or producer where you can use consumer template to consume files.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi @Gnana Guru ,Thank you so much for your response.Every where before stopping the context we are writing Thread.sleep(1000) like that.But how can I exactly know whether the routes are finished or not?  I have a context like mycontext.addRoutes(myRoute); and trying to know the status with myContext.getRouteStatus("myRoute") ,but it is returning null value